# DeVeDe 3.21.0 is not producing working titles in 12.04

Tags: 12.04

DeVeDe 3.21.0 produces an DVD for playback in DVD players, but the Title menu does not show up.

Comment: Are you asking how to make titles in DeVeDe, or are you trying to report a bug about how this functionality is broken? If you think you've found a bug, I encourage you to report it, but AskUbuntu is not the right place for bug reports. Instead, [this is how to report a bug in Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).

Comment: The bug has already been reported, and it is poor practice to post a duplicate bug report.

Comment: That is why I linked to instructions that explicitly and very prominently explain that one should search for existing reports first, and how to do so. In the future, it may be helpful if you mention that a bug has already been reported, if you know that one has been. You can link to the bug, too. (I recommend editing [your answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/144173/22949) to link to it, unless that DeVeDe forum thread *is* the bug report. Also, please note that it is *not* bad practice to report bugs downstream that are already upstream, though you should always link them upstream when doing so.)

Comment: Those reading these comments might like to know that this Q&A was not intended to be a bug report, but to provide a workaround to those not aware of rastersoft.com and the DeVeDe forum.  DeVeDe was developed and is maintained by a very nice fellow, Sergio Costas Rodríguez, owner of rastersoft.com, and who uses the forum for support and problem reporting.

Comment: If DeVeDe had been developed by an organization (i.e. Gnome, Debian) with bug tracking then the formal upstream/downstream approach would be appropriate.  To burden the hardworking folks at Canonical and other Ubuntu developers with an unneeded bug report would be unhelpful. The link in my answer is to the DeVeDe forum, a Google group.

Comment: DeVeDe is maintained in Debian (and Ubuntu) by the [Debian Multimedia Maintainers](https://launchpad.net/~pkg-multimedia-maintainers) team (see [`devede` in Ubuntu's Launchpad package info](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/devede)). Quite a few downstream `devede` bugs have status fixed released. I hope you're not seriously suggesting it's bad to report downstream bugs in DeVeDe. If you don't want to file a report, that's fine. But please don't tell other people not to file bugs because it would somehow create too much of a burden on developers, unless you are one of the developers.

Comment: The Debian Multimedia Maintainers supports 1113 packages with 20 members.  Their purpose is to support other maintainers,  The maintainer of DeVeDe knows of this bug as seen in his forum.  I stand by my statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was found [here](https://groups.google.com/group/devede-forum/browse_thread/thread/8a87b2841c520038).

It seems that DeVeDe versions after 3.18 have this bug when using 12.04.

Reverting to 3.18 works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after updating to Ubuntu 12.04. The solution is to uncheck the "Use FFMPEG instead of Mencoder" in Edit -> Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug report for this, however, there hasn't been done anything about it yet, please click affects me too, if you are affected: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/devede/+bug/1034457

Sorry for posting this as an answer, but my reputation isn't high enough comment on solutions or questions.